# How to get the actual size of LFS file?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have files tracked with git LFS, and I use git ls-tree command to list the files with file size, but I found the size of LFS tarcked files is very small(134 Bytes, its actual size is more than 100MB), I know it's the size of LFS pointer file. Does any one know how to get the actual file size?

use command "git ls-tree -l HEAD" to list the repository tree

Answer (score 21):

[`git lfs ls-files -s`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-ls-files.1.ronn#synopsis)

> -s --size: Show the size of the LFS object between parenthesis at the end of a line.